# create a pop up window inside function

Tags: javascript

What my code trying to do is to add new group if it is not yet created,well, that's work fine now however I also want to open a new popup window as soon as the group is created, prompting user to invite other, but I don't seems to get my work working, any idea on how to make it works?

thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function addGroup()
{
  x=document.getElementById("group").getElementsByTagName("p");
  groups=document.getElementById("groupName");
  var j=0,i=0;  


  if   (groups.value=="")
  {
      alert('must create one group');
  }



   for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
   { 
     if (x[i].innerHTML == groups.value)
     {
         alert('the group name is already created');
         return false;
     }  
   }



   if (!j)
   {
      var newNode=document.createElement('p');
      var newString=document.createTextNode(groups.value); 
      newNode.appendChild(newString);
      x[0].parentNode.appendChild(newNode);
      newWindow();
   }
}

function newWindow()
{
    window.open('http://invite Others.html','invite  
                         others','width=400,height=200,toolbar=yes,                             
      location=yes,directories=yes,status=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=yes,
                             resizable=yes');
      winObj.focus();
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="group">
<ul>
   <p>Group03</p>
   <p>Group02</p>
</ul>
</div>

<p><input type="text" id="groupName" size="84" maxlength="84" value=""/></p>
<p><input type="button" value="create" onclick="addGroup()" /></p>
<p><input type="button" value="remove" onclick="removeNo()"/> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be window.open(). http://invite others.html is not a valid webaddress thus it returns an error.

Firebug returned this when I click create.

```
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMJSWindow.open]" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: http://localhost/ :: newWindow :: line 43" data: no]
```

However if you use http://localhost/invite Others.html it works fine. So just add your hostname after the htttp:// and you should be good to go.

Comment: what do you mean with hostname? is it just by inserting the word "localhost". I tried it but it does not seem to work. the invite others.html is in the same directory with this file. Couldn't I just use "invite others.html", but why it does not work? sory new to javascript

Comment: if you did window.open('newfile.html') that would work. Either remove the HTTP portion of the file path, or use your DNS name Ex: http://www.google.com/myfile.js